# Finding eccentricity of an ellipse from latus rectum

Tags: conic-sections

The latus rectum of an ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ is the same as latus rectum of a parabola $y^2=4cx$ . Find eccentricity of the ellipse .

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: by definition, that ellipse's eccentricity is $$\frac1{\max(a,b)}\sqrt{|a^2-b^2|}$$ so what the latus rectum's business is here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

from [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SemilatusRectum.html) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Features), the length of the latus rectum of the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$  is $2a(1-e^2)$ and $b^2=a^2(1-e^2)$ where $a$ is [Semi](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SemimajorAxis.html) [major](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-major_axis)  Axis, $b$ is the Semi-minor Axis and $e$ is the [Eccentricity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Eccentricity.html)

and the length of the latus rectum of the parabola $y^2=4ax$ is $4a$

Can you utilize the relations to find the value of $e$

Check separately for cases when $a\ge b$ and when $a<b$

**EDIT**: after a drastic change in the question $y^2=4ax$ to $y^2=4cx$

Now WLOG, we can choose $a\ge b$

As the focus of the parabola is $(c,0)$ and those of the ellipse are $(\pm ae,0)$

$c=ae$

Now, $2a(1-e^2)=4c=4ae\implies 1-e^2=2e\implies e^2+2e-1=0$

$\implies e=\frac{-2\pm{\sqrt{2^2-4(-1)1}}}{2\cdot1}=-1\pm\sqrt2$

As $0\le e<1, e=\sqrt2-1$

Comment: Focus of ellipse must coincide with focus of parabola. And following your relations as well. But I am unable to produce a final answer

Comment: @dkbose, if $a\ge b,2a(1-e^2)=4a\implies 1-e^2=2\implies e^2=-1$ which is impossible. If $a<b, 2b(1-e^2)=4a$ and $a^2=b^2(1-e^2)$ eliminate $b$ to get $1-e^2=2$  which is also impossible

Comment: I am extremely sorry , there was a typo in the problem which changed the whole meaning drastically .

Comment: @dkbose, can you manage with the suggestions supplied already?

Comment: Basically , I am struggling with the answer . I can award you a bounty of 50 rep in 2 days to duly award your help .

Comment: @dkbose, if $a\ge b, 2a(1-e^2)=4c\implies 1-e^2=\frac{2c}a\implies e^2=1-\frac{2c}a$ and if $a<b, 2b(1-e^2)=4c$. What is your problem?

Comment: What is the final eccentricity $\frac{1}{\sqrt c}$ ? My book doesn't agree .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8932/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-dkbose)